# 2.92 f12 Cycles HDRI renders Black

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

No matter what I do no light from World HDRI in Cycles render. Just renders BLACK. Please view the attached pic to set up. So frustrating World and Viewport hdri are not synced

[image]

Comment: Got it, IN Properties > Render Layer > Filter > Include - the Environment was not checked, OMG is there not a way to build a UI that doesn't hide and spend stuff all over the place?

Comment: If you found a solution, please write it on the answers section so 
that other users with a similar question can learn from your 
experience. Read:
[Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

You say in your photo that the node is an Environment Map, yet you are using an *Image Texture* Node - you must use an *Environment Texture* Node. There is no such option as "Flat" on an *Environment Texture* Node:

[image: Enviro]